# How to make a loop that successively includes one more element of a numpy array in order to calculate the running variance?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, variance

I have numbers stored in an array like `[1, 6, 12, 4...]`.  I want to do a calculation where each new iteration will use one more element of the array.

- For example, the first iteration will use only the number `1`.
- The second iteration will use `1` and `6`.
- The third will use `1`, `6`, and `12`, and so on.

**More detail for anyone interested in statistics/variance in Python:**

I want to calculate running variance on the data in the array. It seems straightforward to get variance on a whole array in Python. So I'll put my array up to element `i` inside the loop.  I will calculate variance on the array as looping progresses and the array "grows."  If anyone knows a better way to do this, I would be grateful to know.

Comment: Use slicing - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purpose of calculating the running variance on a numpy array, you can use slices in a list comprehension as follows:

```
import numpy as np
a = [1, 6, 12, 4]
running_var = [np.var(a[:i+1]) for i in range(len(a))]
print(running_var)
#[0.0, 6.25, 20.222222222222225, 16.1875]
```

But as your list grows big, you're going to be wasting computations. A more efficient way would be to keep track of the running sum of the values in `a` and the running sum of the squares of `a`.

```
running_sum = 0.
running_sum_of_squares = 0.
running_var = []
for i,x in enumerate(a):
    running_sum += x
    running_sum_of_squares += x*x
    n = i+1.
    running_var.append((running_sum_of_squares - running_sum*running_sum/n)/n)
print(running_var)
#[0.0, 6.25, 20.222222222222225, 16.1875]
```

This computation is for the population variance, but you can easily adjust it for the sample variance.

---

### Timing results

Just to demonstrate the vast speed improvement of the second method, here is a timing comparison:

**Create large random sample**

```
np.random.seed(0)
N = 100000
a = np.random.randn(N)
```

**Method 1: List comprehension**

```
%%timeit
running_var = [np.var(a[:i+1]) for i in range(len(a))]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 11.1 s per loop
```

**Method 2: Incremental variance calculation**

```
def get_running_var(a):
    running_sum = 0.
    running_sum_of_squares = 0.
    running_var = []
    for i,x in enumerate(a):
        running_sum += x
        running_sum_of_squares += x*x
        n = i+1.
        running_var.append((running_sum_of_squares - running_sum*running_sum/n)/n)
    return running_var

%%timeit
get_running_var(a)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 60.5 ms per loop
```

For an array of size 100,000, the incremental calculation is over 180 times faster!

---

I couldn't run the speed test on the [@user3483203's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56381248/5858851) with `N = 100000` due to a `MemoryError`, so I repeated the tests for an array of size 10,000.

The results were the following:

- List comprehension: 100 loops, best of 3: 268 ms per loop
- Incremental Variance: 100 loops, best of 3: 6.09 ms per loop
- user3483203's method: 1 loop, best of 3: 5.73 s per loop

Comment: I really appreciate this because my arrays are huge.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how efficient you want to be, you can do it different ways.

The most direct is to use sum up to the current value using slices:

```
ls = [1, 6, 12, 4]

for i in range(len(ls)):
    print(sum(ls[:i+1]))
```

However you'll find that over time, an accumulator pattern will perform much better. The code below removes the call to `sum`, reducing the computational complexity of the loop to O(n). It should perform noticably faster on large datasets with hundreds of thousands of items:

```
ls = [1, 6, 12, 4]

total = 0
for item in ls:
    total += item
    print(total)
```

This is such a common pattern that it can be convenient to create a reusable function. The code below lets you replace `foo` behaviour with other behaviour:

```
def accumulate(fn, iterable):
    total = 0
    for i, item in iterable:
        total = fn(i, item, total)

def foo(i, item, total):
    print(f'The running total is {total}.')
    return total + 2 * item - i

accumulate(foo, [1, 6, 12, 4])
```

---

```
>>> The running total is 2.
>>> The running total is 13.
>>> The running total is 35.
>>> The running total is 40.
```

Comment: Don't name lists `list`, it overrides the builtin

Comment: @user3483203 Thanks. I work with quite a few languages and when I don't have the docs or interpreter in front of me it's easy to miss details like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *[slices](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/slice)*:

```py
>>>> seq = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>> for i in range(len(seq)):
....     print(sum(seq[:i+1]))
....
1
3
6
10
```

Hope it helps.